# 3D Input to Feed-Forward Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I have a 3D input dataset. The dimensions are (24,80,42). 80 number of timesteps or samples. Each timestep has 24 entities and each entity is attributed to 42 features. How do I give this as input to an ordinary Feed-forward Neural Network? I have already got results with LSTM.

This is the error I'm getting. 
I don't know how to reshape the data to give as input.

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_3_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1920, 42)

```
input_shape = (80,24,42)
network = models.Sequential()

# Add fully connected layer with a ReLU activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(units=42, activation='relu', 
input_shape=input_shape))

# Add fully connected layer with a ReLU activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(units=42, activation='relu'))

# Add fully connected layer with no activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(units=24))
network.summary()
```

Is this correct ?

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

dense_25 (Dense)             (None, 80, 24, 42)        1806

---

dense_26 (Dense)             (None, 80, 24, 42)        1806

---

## dense_27 (Dense)             (None, 80, 24, 24)        1032

Total params: 4,644
Trainable params: 4,644
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Comment: How do you envision the network working, in model/math language?